# In Android, Why can`t operate a UI element in the non-ui thread?

Tags: android

As we know, when we update the UI from the non-ui-thread, we use Handler or AsyncTask. We can find a lot of articles on how to use these methods on the Internet. But I cannot find an explanation on why a UI element cannot be operated from the non-ui thread? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I can only speculate that it has to do with performance... If they allowed multiple threads to access the ui, they would have to add synchronization in many areas which would negatively impact ui performance, giving users a poor experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this decision was made by the Android team (and many other UI frameworks for that matter) because of the following reasons

1. Synchronization
2. Security
3. Performance

**Synchronization**

The simplest reason for following a single threaded model for UI is that *it is the easiest way to ensure that the User Interface is not being updated by multiple sources at once and therefore, corrupted*. If you imagine that multiple threads can modify the UI, it would take each thread its own amount of time to execute a portion of its code, and with the different execution speeds generate a bad user experience.

**Security**

Ensuring that one thread can access the UI is also a security measure, preventing any slave threads that accidentally (or purposefully) try to corrupt the UI from doing so, simply by not allowing it.

**Performance**

The core fact of the matter here is that UI operations, and re-rendering and re-drawing visual layers and elements is an expensive process. It can affect the performance of the framework and cause leaks or lags with the deadlocks and synchronisation in-between. So I believe this was done for the sake of performance too :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because a UI is a state machine, having multiple threads operate on a single state machine makes it difficult or impossible to reason about the current state of the UI and what transitions are available at any given time. There would be unpredictable results, so it's best to keep it separated from code executing in an AsyncTask.